# Firebase Analytics: DebugView double events sometimes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Basically I have a simple code that sends multiple events:

```
        for (i in 1..2) {
            val bundle = Bundle().apply {
                putInt("step", i)
                putString("key", "value")
            }

            mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("test_event", bundle)
        }
```

Despite the fact that events are logged separately, sometimes they are displayed doubled (or combined) in DebugView, so [it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juJFc.png)

But sometimes events [are shown separately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWVjT.png) (as normal).

Any ideas why this happen? Logcat shows the events are being sent separately.

P.S. The real case scenario when I noticed this behavior is tracking the viewed products in the list (RecyclerView), when the user quickly scrolls the list and the events are doubled in the DebugView.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Firebase hasn't addressed this issue cause I'm having it as well. I was able to work around the issue in two different ways.

1. Add a delay at the bottom of the for loop between each item. **NOT PREFERRED**

```js
for (i in 1..2) {
  val bundle = Bundle().apply {
    putInt("step", i)
    putString("key", "value")
  }

  mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("test_event", bundle)
  // Add minor sleep, wait, setTimeout.
}
```

2. Call another event at the end of the for loop so it splits your "test_event" calls.

```js
for (i in 1..2) {
  val bundle = Bundle().apply {
    putInt("step", i)
    putString("key", "value")
  }
  mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("test_event", bundle)

  val bundle2 = Bundle().apply {
    putString("EventCategory", "relevant category")            
    putString("EventAction", "relevant action")
    putString("EventLabel", "relevant label")
  }
  mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("all_events", bundle)
}
```

FYI these code snippets don't run without error. I just copied the questioners code since I'm not sure what language he's using.